# Adding route for admin controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have placed all my admin controllers inside an *Admin* folder in *Controller* folder. Since one of my admin controller matches the name of another controller in *Controller* folder, I am getting the following error.

> *Multiple types were found that match the controller named 'Product'. This can happen if the route that services this request ('{controller}/{action}/{id}') does not specify namespaces to search for a controller that matches the request. If this is the case, register this route by calling an overload of the 'MapRoute' method that takes a 'namespaces' parameter.*

I tried adding the following route, but still the problem is same

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "", //Route name 
    "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}", // Url with parameters 
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

How can i get rid of this error. Changing the name of controller is the last option on my mind. Right now, I am looking for a way to preserve the name and see if i can find another way around this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I have placed all my admin controllers inside an Admin folder in Controller folder

Well, that's your problem. How do you expect the default controller factory to know which controller you want to be instantiated given the following request `/admin/index` (the one in the Controllers folder or the on in the Controllers/Admin folder)? Remember that the default controller factory searches for types in the loaded assemblies that derive from Controller. It doesn't really care in which folder they were declared. So when it finds that you have 2 controllers with the same name it doesn't know which one to pick.

One possibility is to use Areas. Then you could specify namespaces when registering the route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "", 
    "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new[] { "AppName.Areas.Admin.Controllers" }
);
```

Also in your Global.asax make sure that you specify the namespace for the non-area controllers:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new[] { "AppName.Controllers" }
);
```

Comment: thanks....that's what i was looking to achieve. I had the notion that the controller factory doesn't care about the folders and all. But was unable to find the solution you gave. Even the articles on asp.net website didn't touched this issue

Comment: BTW do i need to add `Areas` into the namespace. Wouldn't just `AppName.Admin.Controllers` do the trick ?

Comment: @PankajUpadhyay, this will depend on whether you use areas or not and in what namespaces are your controllers organized.

Comment: It's not that robust. I have renamed my admin controller namespaces to `PriceCompare.Areas.Admin.Controllers`. This solves the problem but i can visit any general controller by adding `Admin/` in front of it. Also, I can visit my admin controllers directly without `Admin/` in front of them.